# Padding from logo - HTML

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I have a problem with header of email, which I send by google apps script in HTML format. I created layout, here is code:

```
<body>
<div id="logo" style="padding:10px 8px 10px 8px; font-family: arial,sans-serif">
    <img src="logo.png" />
    <span class="title" style="color: #808080; font-size: 35px; padding-left: 530px">Lorem </span>
</div>
...
```

In chrome as well as in Gmail it is displayed correctly 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b48KE.jpg)

However email in outlook is displayed incorrect [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu6m2.jpg)

Could someone help me, how to modify HTML code, I want to title (Lorem) on the right side. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would start by adding a float:right to the span

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100% that it will work, but you can try giving `display: inline-block;` to `<img>` and `<span>` tags.

**OR**

if still not work, you might get by positions *absolute* and *relative*.

```
#logo {
    position: relative;
}
#logo span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```